# Python multiprocessing.Pool new process for each variable

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing.Pool in order to loop through a variable and make API calls to a third party program. The problem is that the API has some garbage collection issues, so I need a completely new process for each variable value that I want to run. Is there any way to force multiprocessing to close and launch a new process for each value in my list?

A simple example of my code is this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool()
vals = range(0,100)
result = pool.map(api_call_function, vals)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting [maxtasksperchild](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) to `1` should force Pool to create a new process for each task:

```
pool = Pool(maxtasksperchild=1)
```

Comment: I was digging all around in the mulitprocessing documentation, but somehow missed that.  Marking as solved, thanks!